# Estou com um pequeno problema com listbox - em Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Bom dia, estou com uma dúvida sobre o listbox no tkinter.

meu código está funcionando bem, só tem duas coisas de errado e eu não estou conseguindo arrumar isso.

primeiro que quando eu clico no botão excluir, o programa exclui só na hora, quando eu fecho e reabro o programa a linha que eu tinha excluído reaparece novamente.

e outro problema é que a partir da segunda vez que eu abro o programa a linha toda fica entre chaves "{ }" conforme as imagens abaixo:

*Foto do primeiro problema*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Foto do segundo problema*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue o código completo:

```
from tkinter import*
import sqlite3

class a:
    def __init__(self):
        b = Tk()
        b.geometry("700x600+75+150")
        b.overrideredirect(True)
        b["bg"] = "WHITE"

        def Fechar(): b.destroy()

        cabeçalho = Label(b, background="WHITE")
        cabeçalho.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.lin0xcol0 = Label(cabeçalho, text="CONTROLE DE DOCUMENTOS",border=0, relief=FLAT, background="WHITE", width=94)
        self.lin0xcol0.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.lin0xcol1 = Button(cabeçalho, width=4, border=0, relief=FLAT, background="RED", cursor="X_cursor", command=Fechar)
        self.lin0xcol1.grid(row=0, column=1)


        self.linha1 = Label(b, text="Número de Ofício : Assunto : Local : Observação", font=("Arial", 11),border=0, relief=FLAT, background="WHITE", foreground="BLUE")
        self.linha1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.linha2 = Entry(b, width=110, border=1, relief=SOLID)
        self.linha2.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.linha3 = Button(b, text="ADICIONAR", width=15, background="BLUE", foreground="WHITE", relief=FLAT, command=self.adicionar)
        self.linha3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=8, sticky=E)

        c = Label(b, border=0, relief=FLAT, background="WHITE")
        c.grid(row=4, column=0)

        self.listbox = Listbox(c, width=107, height=25, border=0)
        self.listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)

        #for i in range(100):
        #    listbox.insert(END, i)

        # attach listbox to scrollbar

        self.rolagem = Scrollbar(c)
        self.rolagem.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S, pady=10)

        self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand=self.rolagem.set)
        self.rolagem.config(command=self.listbox.yview)

        self.linha4 = Button(b, text="EXCLUIR", width=15, background="RED", foreground="WHITE", relief=FLAT, command=self.apagar)
        self.linha4.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20, sticky=E)

        #       BANCO DE DADOS

        self.conectar = sqlite3.connect("ofícios.db")
        self.cursor = self.conectar.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS oficios(oficios TEXT)")
        self.conectar.commit()
        lista = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM oficios")
        for i in lista:
        self.listbox.insert(END, i)

    def adicionar(self):
        oficiosx = self.linha2.get()
        self.cursor.execute("insert into oficios values(?)", (oficiosx,))
        self.conectar.commit()
        self.listbox.insert(END, oficiosx)

    def apagar(self):
        oficiosy = str(self.listbox.get(ACTIVE))[3:-3]
        self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM oficios WHERE oficios=?", (oficiosy,))
        self.conectar.commit()
        self.listbox.delete(ANCHOR)
        return

        b.mainloop()
a()
```

Comment: Bom dia ! Ja pensou em utilizar ttk.treeview ? Em minha opniao seria melhor para seu programa

Comment: Infelizmente com a treeview acontece a mesma coisa. Creio que se eu conseguir resolver com listbox, será válida até para a treeview também.